# Source request of axiom of Archimedes

Tags: reference-request, math-history, axioms

I'm a little confused with axiom of Archimedes has a proof since it is an axiom. So I'm guessing there's a historical reason that this property of ordered field was given such a name. Is there any material for this?

Comment: Archimedes states it explicitly as an assumption, in *On the sphere and cylinder*. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property). The book itself can be seen [here](https://archive.org/details/worksofarchimede00arch).

Comment: Would you feel better if it were called "Property of Archimedes"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would like to say "Archimedes' Theorem"

Comment: But those are just words, some of which have historical and traditional roots. We prove the **axiom** of choice, by assuming Zorn's **lemma**. And Bertrand's **postulate** is a **theorem** as well. Fermat's Last **Theorem** was no more than a **hypothesis** for over three centuries, and Poincare **Conjecture** is not going to be renamed as Poincare-Perelman **Theorem** anytime soon.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. Reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "Archimedean axiom" was introduced by [Otto Stolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Stolz) around 1883.  Later, [Johan Heiberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Ludvig_Heiberg_%28historian%29) noticed that this is closely related to an axiom appearing in Euclid V.4. The term has become commonly accepted since then. It should be noted that none of the European mathematicians from [Simon Stevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin) and until the end of the 19th century used the term in this sense, so in a way the commonly accepted term "archimedean field" is somewhat ahistorical, which does not detract from its usefulness. For details see [this article](http://www.ams.org/notices/201307/rnoti-p886.pdf).